# Python Logging: Change "WARN" to "INFO"

Tags: python, django, logging

If our Django web application returns a 404, we see this in the logs:

```
2017-11-21 12:48:26 django.request.get_response: WARNING Not Found: /foooooo
```

I would like to change this particular line created by get_response() from WARN to INFO.

How to configure this with Django and Python?

An alternative solution would be to ignore this line, but WARN to INFO would be preferred.

Comment: If you "can solve this on your own", then IMO my answer contains enough detail to get someone with that mindset started down the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly create logger filter

```
def change_404_level_to_INFO(record):
    if record.status_code == 404:
        record.levelname = 'INFO'
    return True
```

After that in `LOGGING` add this filter and set filter on logger

```
LOGGING = {
....
    'filters': {
        'change_404_to_INFO': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': change_404_to_INFO`,
        },
    },
....
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console',],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate: False,
            'filters': ['change_404_to_INFO'],
        },
    }
....
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this easily, because the Django developers have decided that this particular event is important enough to be classed as a `WARNING`.

However, you *can* convert it to `INFO` when writing to a log, by adding an instance of a `logging.Filter` subclass which changes the level in the `LogRecord` from `WARNING` to `INFO`, or filters out the message altogether.

The filter should be added to any handler whose output should be changed in this way. This can be done using standard Django logging configuration mechanisms.

Comment: I guess I can solve this on my own. On the other hand I think 10 developers would do it in 10 different ways. Which is the most pythonic way?